# Is Xmas 24th a common way to refer to 24th December (Christmas Eve)?

Tags: south-australia, terminology, 1900s-decade

I recently received an image from the inside cover of a book ("The Poetical Works of Lord Byron") that I believe belonged to my great grandmother Mary Ellen Nettell (1869-1932) who was known as "Nellie".

At the time, Nellie would have been living in a suburb of Adelaide, South Australia, but she was born to Cornish parents in Angaston, South Australia and grew up there, possibly with some German influences from its other early settlers.

[image]

The easy to read inscription is:

> To dear Nellie from Sadie With fondest love Xmas 24th. 1908.

I am sure the date being referred to is 24 Dec 1908, and while I commonly see "Christmas Eve" written as "Xmas Eve", I have never seen it written as "Xmas 24th".

Is "Xmas 24th" a way to refer to Christmas Eve that anyone has come across?

---

Note: I tried [searching on the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=xmas%2024th), and although probably on topic for both sites, I thought I would post here in preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have seen dates such as Xmas 24TH & New Year 30TH. Mainly people from the Philippines, Caribbean, and South America, but it pops up closer to my home in Northern Kentucky/Southern Ohio, too. It may have been started by the missionaries to help translate that Christmas EVENING is an entire day, and lasts all morning, noon, and evening of the 24th.

The "New Year 30TH" may be a more recent term, coined by "Xmas 24th" users. Since New Year's Eve IS celebrated in the evening, New Year 30th describes the day before. Haven't found any references, but here are a couple videos using the term:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yResKE_HgOE (Vietnamese-American family)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYrdh_ynwzw (European-American family)

Comment: Are there any references that you can cite? And wouldn't New Year 31ST rather than 30TH be more likely used? Where is home?

Comment: Home is Northern Kentucky/Southern Ohio. The "New Year 30TH" may be a more recent term, coined by "Xmas 24th" users. Since New Year's Eve IS celebrated in the evening, New Year 30th describes the day before. Haven't found any references, but here are a couple videos using the term - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yResKE_HgOE (Vietnamese-American family) & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYrdh_ynwzw (European-American family)